# Physical location of a teams data

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, architecture

I've managed to figure out that Stack Overflow for teams is hosted in Azure, but I am wondering what their geographical location is?

Is it possible to restrict the data's location to European datacenters or are there no guarantees as to where the data is physically located?

Comment: I'm curious about why you'd like this. I'm guessing you'd like local law to apply to the data center, or something like that..?

Comment: pretty much yeah. Main reason is that our company requires us to answer where the data is geographically stored, because we apparently have to do some extra laps around technical compliance if the data is stored in the US.
so it would be less work for us if we could lock it to the EU.

Comment: Researched guess: "We have [two datacenters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333095/282094), with our main datacenter in New York (actually New Jersey) and the secondary in Colorado.". You need to pay for [Enterprise Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/security), then pay Microsoft for a region: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Teams on the non-Enterprise level, data is hosted in the US only. Specifically, the same as our regular data centers, in New York (*ish*) and Colorado.

For Teams on the Enterprise level, customers can currently select from a variety of approved Azure hosting regions located in the US, Canada, UK, Europe, and Australia.

Comment: Saying UK and Europe as if we're not part of Europe :sadface: it's only the EU we left, we haven't moved our little island

Comment: @Nick Fun story regarding that, when it comes to Azure regions, apparently your choices are: "Austria, Denmark, Europe, France, Germany, Greece, Italy, Norway, Poland, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom". Europe consists of Ireland and Netherlands.

Comment: I-I don't even know how to react to that...